# iPhone - adjusting the size of a UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, ipad

I need to present a UIActionSheet that will show 10 buttons. When I do that on iPad, the UIActionSheet shows on a popover that is very long vertically (not aesthetically pretty). Is that possible to specify the UIActionSheet size to a maximum size?

I have tried this

```
myActionSheet.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,300);
myActionSheet.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,300,300);
```

and have also tried to put these lines inside

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
```

without success.

any clues?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is one of the cases where you can't really use a built-in class like the `UIActionSheet` to accomplish your goal. I don't think it is designed to be used for cases where you have as many buttons as 10. It just doesn't scale very well, just as you have discovered.

But let's pretend that it would be possible to change the size. What should happen when you change the size? There is a minimum size for each button for it to be tapable. And you also need some space between the buttons as to not cause a misstap. So even if you could change the size it couldn't be reduced by very much. And since it's not intended to be able to change the size you would have to try and access all the buttons and resize and move them as well. One could argue that perhaps the buttons could be placed in columns but since that is not implemented it would still not help if you made the `UIActionSheet` any wider.

I would recommend that you either:

1. Create your own custom view with all 10 buttons placed just as you liked.
2. Use a table view to present the options. Since the table view can be scrolled you can get the size you like.

If you set `modalInPopover` to `YES` on the `UIViewController` you present in the popover the user must make a choice before she can move on.

Comment: when you add many buttons to a UIActionSheet it keeps all buttons on their regular size and spacing and creates a scrollable list something like a table. Anyone I have decided to change that with a table. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try with `- (void)showFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated
because in apple documentation they said:
"On iPad, this method displays the action sheet in a popover whose arrow points to the specified rectangle of the view. The popover does not overlap the specified rectangle."

`

Comment: Sorry but I cannot grasp the meaning of your answer to what I have asked. I am already doing this and my problem is the huge size of the popover being presented already...

Comment: i thought that method will help you to resize the uiactionsheet view.

Comment: no, the area specifies where the popover will point to, not its size... :(