# How to change the width of UIActionSheet in iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to change the width of UIActionSheet in iPad, and I tried to set a new frame size for the UIActionSheet, but nothing changed.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is not accomplished with the built in onw, you need to create your own custom view.

> 1. Create your own custom view with all 10 buttons placed just as you liked.
> 2. Use a table view to present the options. Since the table view can be scrolled you can get the size you like.

Reference: [adjusting the size of a UIActionSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258596/iphone-adjusting-the-size-of-a-uiactionsheet/4259641#4259641)